# Image place holder with Picasso - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, picasso

I'm using Picasso in my app in a listview, the issue I'm facing is that when I load images with  `Picasso.with(context).load("file:///path/to/image/in/SD").into(imageView)` 
and scroll the listvie,w the loaded images pushes the list up or down when the image is loaded, below depicts what I'm trying to say.

```
item 1
========
item 2 
========
item 3
```

Now let's say I scrolled up and the list stopped at position 15

```
item 15  ///Picasso started loading the image but the image isn't ready yet
========
item 16 
========
item 17



item 15  //after few milliseconds the image is loaded into the image view

image view is loaded and pushed the list down
---------
|       |
|       | 
|       |
---------

========
item 16 
========
item 17
```

The images I have are all locally saved with their path in the DB. Facebook is doing that very nicely where they use a gray image and then they load an image with the same dimension of the gray placeholder, and btw the placeholder changes based on the image.

The question is how can I put a place holder like a black or gray image as a place holder that has the same dimension of the image that will be loaded after the load is completed so it replaces it without pushing the list?

Please note that using  .placeholder() isn't good because the size is not gonna be the same.

Comment: You could set the minimum and maximum size of the imageViews. This way and in conjunction with the placeholder, the list will not 'jump'. But to provide a placeholder that is dynamically in size depending of the image to load, facebook needs to fetch the size of the image first. You could do this, too. Prefetch alle image sizes, add accordingly the place holders and lazy load the images.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the target image view size but for that you need to know the target size before starting DLing the image using picasso. It just wont work automatically for you. It should somehow to get know the target image size. If speaking about list with images DLed from internet then usually app gets all needed info about image (url, size etc) before it goes to DL it. An your app has all images in resources of the project. So to achieve your goal you should use `BitmapFactory` to get image size before giving a task to load it to picasso.

Comment: I can save the size of the images in the DB along with it's SD path, now let's say I have saved it in DB how can I do what you suggested?

Comment: Picasso has a corresponding method: .resize(imageWidth, imageHeight)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get the whole picture here, I have the image size, how does that help? how should I create the placeholder while loading the image?

Comment: set the same placeholder image and set size using resize. set imageview scaleType to fitXY